# Function template palindrome that takes a vector parameter

Tags: c++, templates, vector, stl

I'm starting to learn C++ and STL.
  I have a problem:

Write a function template palindrome that takes a vector parameter and returns true or false to check whether the vector is palindrome or not (12321 is palindrome, 1234 isn't palindrome)

And this is my code:

```
template<class T>
bool palindrome(vector<T> & v)
{ 
  int i,j;
  for( i=0,j=v.size();i<v.size()/2;i++,j--)
  {
      if(v[i]!=v[j]) 
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}

void main()
{
  int ar[]={1,2,3,2,1};
  vector<int> v(ar,ar+5);
  cout<<palindrome(v);
}
```

The code doesn't work. I know it has some mistakes but I don't know how to fix them. Please, help me!
Thank you very much!

Comment: What's the exact error message? What output do you expect and what output do you get?

Comment: Try using iterators `rbegin` , instead of using size(), not the best way of iterating over a vector.

Comment: main should return an int, not a void.

Comment: You could just use a bidirectional iterator approach instead, with `template<typename Iterator> palindrome(Iterator begin, Iterator end)` and pass `v.begin()` and `v.end()`. Just a thought.

Answer (score 4):

You have your indexes incorrect. In your loop `j=v.size()`, and then you access to `v[j]`. But the last element is at index v.size() - 1. Your program behavior will be undefined.

Change to `j=v.size() -1`

Comment: probly better answer than mine, and faster. But, accessing an element beyond the end of the array, for reading will rarely crash an execution.

Comment: Oh That's a fool mistake. Thank you very much. The code worked well.

Answer (score 2):

Most glaring error is in :  `for( i=0,j=v.size();i<v.size()/2;i++,j--)`

You need `j=v.size()-1`

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use your mastery of the STL to compact it right down, and also have it work for lists, and other things.

```
template<class T> bool palindrome(T & v){
    return std::equal(v.begin(),v.end(),v.rbegin());
}
```